# Why Java class not loaded?

Tags: java, classloader

when i debug the following code, I encountered a problem：

```
HotelDomainPrefixUtil.HotelB2BDomainPrefix = Class not loaded: com.xxx.xxx.HotelDomainPrefixUtil
```

The code are following:

```
public class HotelDomainPrefixUtil {
public static List<String> hotelB2BDomainPrefixList;
static {
    hotelB2BDomainPrefixList = some initalization code
    }
}
```

I use `HotelDomainPrefixUtil` like this：

```
public String generatePrefix(DomainGenerateParam domainGenerateParam) {
    for (Iterator<String> iterator = HotelDomainPrefixUtil.hotelB2BDomainPrefixList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {

    }
    // some code
}
```

I don't know where a error happens? But when I change my code like this:

```
    List<String> hotelB2BDomainPrefixList = HotelDomainPrefixUtil.hotelB2BDomainPrefixList;
    for (Iterator<String> iterator = hotelB2BDomainPrefixList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    //some code
    }
```

and I debug my code, everything is ok. But why?

Comment: To maintain secrecy, I can not paste all the code, please forgive me。 thank you

Comment: What Java version and IDE do you use?

Comment: @dds JDK8, bug project language level is 6.0。 and IDE is IntelliJ IDEA 13.1

Comment: Heap dump analysis could be little helpful.

Comment: Can you peek into the generated bytecode to determine the difference? These two versions seem to be semantically identical to me.

Answer (score -1):

Compiler does not recognized 'HotelB2BDomainPrefix'. And I didn't see any 'HotelB2BDomainPrefix' except 'hotelB2BDomainPrefixList' in your code posted. Is there any typo here?

Comment: HotelB2BDomainPrefix is an inner class of HotelDomainPrefixUtil